# Не собирается Qt. Ошибка 0x2

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

Хотел пересобрать Qt5.4.2 под Windows через компилятор VC++ (cl.exe) компании Microsoft.

но на финише (или далеко от финиша) мне выбились ошибки:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'qsqlite.lib'
>
> 'cd' return code 0x2

Как исправить? С WinGW, конечно, всё собирается. Но мне нужны 64-разрядные приложения (MinGW64 не поддерживается официально самой Qt), поэтому хотелось бы собрать через компилятор VC.

Comment: А чем Вам не устраивают официальные сборки? Они есть и для MSVC, в том числе

Comment: А если Вы собираете из самой студии и хотите всё таки собрать Qt, то попробуйте поставить [число параллельных билдов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0xettzf(v=vs.90).aspx) в 1

Comment: Я знаю, что есть готовые либы Qt под компилятор компании Майкрософт. Но пересборка идет с целью получить статическую сборку. Собираю не через саму VS. А через её окружение. Ну в командной строке с настроенным окружением. Там когда надо ввести configure <ключи>. Потом nmake. И ждать.

Comment: покажите строчку, как Вы выполняете `configure`

Comment: Отредактировал файл qmake.conf. Поменял один символ. Только вот не сработало что-то одно: указание команды -prefix <путь>... но это уже не так важно.


вот эта строчка:
configure.bat -release -static -prefix %PREFIX% -extprefix %EXTPREFIX% -hostprefix %HOSTPREFIX% -opengl desktop -c++11 -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-icu -skip qtwebkit -no-sql-sqlite


С ней собралось. Спасибо @zenden2k . Не видел в help, что можно пропустить сборку компонента через -skip

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта: qsqlite.lib у вас собрана или нет. Если нет - смотреть на логи сборки и понимать почему нет, но это уже несколько иная проблема. Если она собрана - смотреть флаги линкера в плане дополнительных путей для либ.

Comment: Так она и не собирается. И даже пытался отключить на этапе конфигурирования через строку -no-sql-sqlite (в списке конфигурирования сборки именно она и стояла по умолчанию). Без толку. Та же ошибка.

Comment: cannot open input file 'qsqlite.lib' означает что какой-то другой проект пытается ее открыть и не может, а не то что она не собирается. Она может лежать немного не там, где ее ищет проект, выдающий ошибку.

Comment: во всём логе сборки поискал... среди "этапов" creating library названия "qsqlite.lib" не встречается абсолютно нигде, кроме этой строчки. она же ошибка.

Comment: В *.pro и *.pri тоже нет ее?

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь вы собираете в чистой директории? А не в той же директории, в которой вы собирали  помощью Mingw?

Скорее всего эта библиотека (qsqlite.lib) нужна не для сборки самой qt, а для сборки примеров или тестов.

Попробуйте так:

```
configure -nomake examples -nomake tests -static
```

Я вообще так собираю статически:

```
configure -debug-and-release -opengl desktop -no-angle -skip qtwebkit -no-icu -release  -nomake tests  -nomake examples  -static  -platform win32-msvc2013 -no-sse2
jom module-qtbase
```

(потому что мне ничего кроме qtbase не нужно)

Comment: `qsqlite.lib`, скорее всего, нужна для драйвера SQLite

Comment: @ixSci qsqlite.lib - это и есть драйвер sqlite. В нестатической сборке он создается вместе с файлом plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlite.dll

Comment: С MinGW я уже удалил. Удалил всё (исходники и собранные). Заново собираю всегда. Сейчас еще раз попробую запустить.